# Would 256.256.256.256 be considered a valid hostname?

Tags: computer-networks

We know an valid IPv4 address is each part not greater than 255, so, will `256.256.256.256` be considered a valid hostname rather an IP address?

I'm just curious how devices in various parts of the internet treat this kind of hostname?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Syntax, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name#Syntax

Comment: @D.W., it took more than trivial scrutiny to get the answer from those links. The simple answer is that ICANN bans all-numeric TLDs, therefore `256.256.256.256` should be parsed as an invalid IP address, not as a host name under the TLD `.256`.

Comment: @Steve, that sounds great -- thank you for doing that research!  Can I encourage you to write that as an answer, so we can upvote it, and so this question will be treated as answered?

Comment: @Steve: Isn't `256.256.256.256` *relative* to the local search-domain? It would only be a host in the `256` TLD if it were `256.256.256.256.`, or am I mistaken? I.e. if my local search-domain is set up to be `xyz.local`, then a lookup for `256.256.256.256` would, at some point in the lookup algorithm, also try to resolve `256.256.256.256.xyz.local`, which is not an all-numeric TLD, and thus *could* succeed if I have set up that particular record in my name server.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I'm not sure to be honest. My understanding (which is not expert in this area) is that before you even get to the point of looking up a DNS record, you have to establish whether a domain name has even been given by the user, or merely an IP address given (which requires no lookup on the name server, because it isn't a name).

Answer (score 2):

As Steve has already pointed out ICANN bans all numeric TLDs. One can find a list of valid TLDs [here](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) at IANA.

This could be the end of this question but if one scrolls all the way down on [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Non-IANA_domains) one can find TLDs which are in fact not managed or tracked by either ICANN or IANA. While Wikipedia is a bit nebulous how they exactly work they provide their respective TLDs so I tried looking up the one that did not have a fixed URL and found something.

[You only need a DNSSEC](https://hsd-dev.org/guides/claims.html) which does not technically require a TLD that is registered with IANA. So you could register 256.256.256.256 as a "legit" URL